# Geting some info from JSON Object and order it

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, oop, google-maps-api-3

I have a really simple question but I have no experience in programming. Im sure there is an easy solution of my problem. I want to collect some info from google directions api, but not all. The problem is how to keep the order because in the step array the info provider are diverent in walking and transit mode :(

I have a JSON Object.

```
                 "steps" : [
                    {
                       "distance" : {
                          "text" : "0,3 km",
                          "value" : 285
                       },
                       "duration" : {
                          "text" : "4 Minuten",
                          "value" : 212
                       },
                       "end_location" : {
                          "lat" : 48.1157184,
                          "lng" : 11.6600491
                       },
                       "html_instructions" : "Auf \u003cb\u003eMönchbergstraße\u003c/b\u003e nach \u003cb\u003eSüdwesten\u003c/b\u003e Richtung \u003cb\u003eHechtstraße\u003c/b\u003e",
                       "polyline" : {
                          "points" : "_audHssdfA^RLHx@b@TLb@V^Rz@d@|@d@~A|@`@RXN"
                       },
                       "start_location" : {
                          "lat" : 48.1180761,
                          "lng" : 11.6615385
                       },
                       "travel_mode" : "WALKING"
                    },
                    {
                       "distance" : {
                          "text" : "13 m",
                          "value" : 13
                       },
                       "duration" : {
                          "text" : "1 Minute",
                          "value" : 10
                       },
                       "end_location" : {
                          "lat" : 48.1157011,
                          "lng" : 11.6602402
                       },
                       "html_instructions" : "\u003cb\u003eLinks\u003c/b\u003e abbiegen auf \u003cb\u003eSt.-Augustinus-Straße\u003c/b\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003eDas Ziel befindet sich auf der linken Seite.\u003c/div\u003e",
                       "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                       "polyline" : {
                          "points" : "grtdHijdfAJ]GG"
                       },
                       "start_location" : {
                          "lat" : 48.1157184,
                          "lng" : 11.6600491
                       },
                       "travel_mode" : "WALKING"
                    }
                 ],
                 "travel_mode" : "WALKING"
              },
              {
                 "distance" : {
                    "text" : "2,5 km",
                    "value" : 2506
                 },
                 "duration" : {
                    "text" : "9 Minuten",
                    "value" : 510
                 },
                 "end_location" : {
                    "lat" : 48.1172364,
                    "lng" : 11.63957
                 },
                 "html_instructions" : "Bus in Richtung Michaelibad",
                 "polyline" : {
                    "points" : "crtdHokdfAFFK^mGpSEPITOp@?@Ml@a@|A}AvGk@~Bk@`C{@xDGLKFI?w@e@C?C?GFyA`G]vAQt@uAnHw@lE]pBQrAYbCq@dF{ArMMt@CDk@Vj@WBELu@YOQIPHXNMt@CDs@ZE?I?GGEGYw@O[AIAMBSFSjBz@XNRHz@XhAb@bA^nEzA~EvBhFzBj@\\]xAOI"
                 },
                 "start_location" : {
                    "lat" : 48.1157011,
                    "lng" : 11.6602402
                 },
                 "transit_details" : {
                    "arrival_stop" : {
                       "location" : {
                          "lat" : 48.1172364,
                          "lng" : 11.63957
                       },
                       "name" : "Heinrich-Wieland-Straße"
                    },
                    "arrival_time" : {
                       "text" : "11:35",
                       "time_zone" : "Europe/Berlin",
                       "value" : 1511606100
                    },
                    "departure_stop" : {
                       "location" : {
                          "lat" : 48.1157011,
                          "lng" : 11.6602402
                       },
                       "name" : "Mönchbergstraße"
                    },
                    "departure_time" : {
                       "text" : "11:26",
                       "time_zone" : "Europe/Berlin",
                       "value" : 1511605590
                    },
                    "headsign" : "Michaelibad",
                    "line" : {
                       "agencies" : [
                          {
                             "name" : "MVG München",
                             "phone" : "011 49 800 344226600",
                             "url" : "http://www.mvg.de/"
                          }
                       ],
                       "color" : "#004d40",
                       "name" : "Neuperlach Süd Bf. - Klinikum Neuperlach - Am Hochacker - St.-Veit-Straße - Michaelibad",
                       "short_name" : "195",
                       "text_color" : "#ffffff",
                       "vehicle" : {
                          "icon" : "//maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/transit/iw2/6/bus2.png",
                          "name" : "Bus",
                          "type" : "BUS"
                       }
                    },
                    "num_stops" : 5
                 },
                 "travel_mode" : "TRANSIT"
              },...
```

How to traverse the object get all necessary info and keep the order. I tried to build a 2 objects. So I save order in walking.key or transit.key. Ok. But how after that use for loop to get all info in order from both objects in a right order. Does my first step has any sense? Or there is the better way?

```
        var walking = {
                distance : [],
                duration : [],
                html_instructions: [],
                key : []
        };

        var transit = {
                distance : [],
                duration : [],
                html_instructions: [],
                busStopName : [],
                departureTime : [],
                vehicle : [],
                number : [],
                route : [],
                headsign :[],
                key: []
        };

        for (key in myResult) {

              if ( (typeof(myResult[key]["travel_mode"])!=="undefined") && myResult[key]["travel_mode"]=== "WALKING") {


                  walking.distance.push(myResult[key]["distance"]["text"]);
                  walking.duration.push(myResult[key]["duration"]["text"]);
                  walking.duration.push(myResult[key]["html_instructions"]);
                  walking.key.push(myResult[key]);
              }     


              if ( (typeof(myResult[key]["travel_mode"])!=="undefined") && myResult[key]["travel_mode"]=== "TRANSIT") {

                  transit.headsign.push(myResult[key]["transit_details"]["headsign"]);
                  transit.busStopName.push(myResult[key]["transit_details"]["departure_stop"]["name"]);
                  transit.departureTime.push(myResult[key]["transit_details"]["departure_time"]["text"]);
                  transit.distance.push(myResult[key]["distance"]["text"]);
                  transit.duration.push(myResult[key]["duration"]["text"]);
                  transit.vehicle.push(myResult[key]["transit_details"]["line"]["vehicle"]["name"]);
                  transit.number.push(myResult[key]["transit_details"]["line"]["short_name"]);
                  transit.route.push(myResult[key]["transit_details"]["line"]["name"]);
                  transit.key.push(myResult[key]);
              }             

            }
```

Comment: That makes sense, but what do you mean by _keep the order_ ?

Comment: I mean that the order of walking or transit can be different

Comment: still not clear for me, would you mind explaining again what are you trying to achieve?